# How to find the latest Date for every number in draw, from Map<Date, List<Integer>>

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Let say I have a `Map<Date, List<Integer>>`, where list of integers is just a list of numbers thrown in lottery draw. It may look like this:

```
Wed Nov 15 13:31:45 EST 2017=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 
Wed Nov 22 13:31:45 EST 2017=[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 
Wed Nov 29 13:31:45 EST 2017=[13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18], 
Wed Dec 13 13:31:45 EST 2017=[1, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23], 
Wed Dec 20 13:31:45 EST 2017=[24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
```

I need to convert that map into the map, where key is the lottery number, and the value is the last date when the number was thrown. Something like:
1=Wed Dec 13 13:31:45 EST 2017
2=Wed Nov 15 13:31:45 EST 2017
etc till 49.

So, the question is: is it possible to make it with the Java 8 streams and if yes, then how.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not mistaken you are looking for something like this (assuming `Date` is `Comparable`):

```
map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(x -> x.getValue().stream().map(y -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(x.getKey(), y)))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Entry::getValue,
                    Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                            Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getKey)),
                            x -> x.get().getKey())));
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. Now I need to understand it. )))

Comment: @EasyRider it might be a lot easier to understand if you put it into an IDE and see what `x,y` are in each step...

Comment: You can simplify the `collect` step by using: `Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, Map.Entry::getKey, BinaryOperator.<Date>maxBy(Comparator.naturalOrder()))`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a succint way to do it (without streams, though):

```
Map<Integer, Date> result = new HashMap<>();
map.forEach((date, list) -> list.forEach(n -> result.merge(n, date, 
    (oldDate, newDate) -> newDate.after(oldDate) ? newDate : oldDate)));
```

This iterates the `map` map and for each one of its `(date, list)` pairs, it iterates the `list` list of numbers. Then it uses the [`Map.merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) and [`Date.after`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after-java.util.Date-) methods to put entries into the `result` map in such a way that only the last date is mapped to a given number.

Comment: I *swear!* I knew I am going to see you here. I enjoyed your last newsletter also (quite a lot)

Comment: @Eugene Thanks for that, man... I really appreciate your support. I'm writing the 2nd part (the digressing intro is ready). Btw, great answer on the flatMap bug, clear from the very beginning. I wish they fixed it so that it's 100% lazy...

Comment: Thank you Federico. It works as well. Also will try to understand. :-)       Sorry, but I've already marked Eugene's answer as accepted.

Comment: @EasyRider Sure, no problem! You asked about streams, and Eugene has answered with a stream-based solution. My answer is here just as a complement to Eugene's.